# Include folder deeply nested in excluded folder

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to exclude everything under a certain path from being copied with rsync except for one path in particular that's deeply nested within it. I tried the approach recommended [here](https://serverfault.com/q/770728/174220):

```
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Torchlight II/my games/
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Torchlight II/my games/**
--exclude=/home/*/.local/share/Steam/**
```

The "my games" folder isn't included in the output, but the "Steam" folder is:

```
.d..t...... home/dave/.local/share/Steam/
```

I thought maybe I needed to explicitly include every subfolder up to the desired one, but this didn't work either:

```
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/**
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/**
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Torchlight II/
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Torchlight II/**
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Torchlight II/my games/
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Torchlight II/my games/**
--exclude=/home/*/.local/share/Steam/**
```

The output of this command included everything under the "Steam" folder except for "Torchlight II". I thought the problem must be the space in the folder name, but other folders are included - even ones that I didn't specifically mean to include - such as "Super Meat Boy". Regardless, I tried escaping them like so:

```
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/**
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/**
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Torchlight\ II/
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Torchlight\ II/**
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Torchlight\ II/my\ games/
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Torchlight\ II/my\ games/**
--exclude=/home/*/.local/share/Steam/**
```

I also tried quoting them:

```
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/**
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/
--include=/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/**
--include="/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Torchlight II/"
--include="/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Torchlight II/**"
--include="/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Torchlight II/my games/"
--include="/home/dave/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Torchlight II/my games/**"
--exclude=/home/*/.local/share/Steam/**
```

The result is the same. It makes no sense to me.

Comment: How exactly did you escape the path?

Comment: @jasperado see update.

Comment: Both, quoting and escaping works for me. Have you tried to get some more information by invoking rsync with -vv

Comment: What folders did you have to include?

Comment: I just gave it a random try with a space in the filename. Though this could of course vary depending on the shell an rsync version you are using. However, what about the rsync -vv?

Comment: With -vv, the files are included in the output. Without, they are not. I can't explain it :\

Comment: Remove the include `"**"` lines except the last one from your last attempt. Remember, the first matching rule, taken in args order, applies, so you want to match each directory only. You can also collapse the last 2 includes into one ending `"***"`. If the files are already at the destination, the `-v` option will not list them, but the `-vv` option will list them and say they are uptodate.